# Filter projects which trigger build in tfs

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Is there any within team build 2010 (tfs) to decouple the projects found under the build's workspace from the projects which will trigger a build?

I'd like to be able to specify a subset of the projects in my workspace as being those that trigger a build when changed. At the moment any change in the active paths of the workspace will trigger a build.

Comment: Why are those projects in the build's workspace if changes to them shouldn't trigger a build?

Comment: They are there because there output is needed for the build, I just want the flexibility of not having them trigger a build. Having this flexibility could prevent a change to a Local.Testsettings or the solution file from triggering *every* build configuration that uses that solution or test settings.

Comment: You have more than one build configuration that uses the same solution? And you don't want to build if you change parts of the solution? Are the Local.testsettings used in unit tests that run as part of the build?

Comment: correct on all three counts John

Comment: Why are the test settings being changed so often that this has become a problem? What other files are being changed often enough for this to be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create more build definitions to build only specific projects. I had two sets of projects, framework and modules projects. I had two CI build definitions, one for framework set and one for modules. If I changed framework project, framework build was triggered and all output assemblies were checked-in into TFS into BuildAssemblies folder. This folder is included in Modules build definition workspace because BuildAssemblies are referenced from modules projects. Normally if I change BuildAssemblies content modules build should be triggered, but I checked my changes with *****NO_CI***** prefix to not trigger modules build.

But this is not good design. If you change framework assembly and break modules build by this change, you don't know about it until you manually trigger modules build. It makes no sense to use gated check-in feature for modules build.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I tend to agree with John Saunders, still:
You can have the projects you wish to not trigger your build in a separate spot within your source control. Remove them from your main solution as projects & add them as assemblies.

This way, any change in your secondary sources will not trigger your main build - merging the compiled assembly will. The gain is that the latter can be done at any time you choose to.

Using file reference has several disadvantages in your case, the main being you can't directly debug the compiled assembly. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047733/project-reference-vs-dll-reference-which-is-better).

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to remove those projects from the build definition's workspace mappings. The projects, of course, are still in the branch and *your* workspace.

Comment: but removing them means I cannot make use of them in the build right?

Comment: What are you using these for if you don't want to build them? If you check in changes to files that you don't need to build, you can use the `***NO_CI***` comment for CI build definitions or bypass gated checkin for gated check in build definition.