# Visual Studio 2015 cannot reference an added project

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The OS is 2012 r2 server. I have Visual Studio 2015 installed. I have migrated two Visual Studio 2010 projects to Visual Studio 2015 successfully. Lets call one of the projects 'main project', and the other one 'second project'. The second project references a NuGet Package.

I added the second project to my main project. Now when I try to add reference to the solution from the folder that has the second project; I don't see the project solution. So I chose 'All Files' from the drop down menu. And then when I try to reference the xxxx.sln or xxxx.csproj file I get the following error: A reference to 'xxxx.sln' (or xxxx.csproj) could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

I cannot build the whole project because the main project uses the second one.

Can any one please tell me how to resolve this issue. Many Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the second project and they are both in the same solution you have the following options.

1. Project Reference - In the left hand pane of the reference manager, select "Projects\Solution". You should then be able to select your second project from there. This will link the second project and update the reference when the project is rebuilt.
2. DLL Reference - Select "Browse" in the Reference Manager and select the built .dll of the second project (not the .sln or .prj)

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047733/project-reference-vs-dll-reference-which-is-better) for an explanation of the difference.