# Do I need to have a hintpath in my csproj file reference?

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

I manually edited in a reference (`Reference` not `ProjectReference`) in my csproj file, and after reviewing the code, I can see that the hintpath is wrong:

```
+    <Reference Include="Company.Core.Data.Web.UnitTests">
+      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Code\Bin\Company.Core.Data.Web.UnitTests.dll</HintPath>
+      <Private>True</Private>
+    </Reference>
```

The right path would be `..\..\..\..\..\Build\UnitTests\Company.Core.Data.Web.UnitTests.dll`.

However, I notice that a clean build of my project works fine. Does this matter? Is this something I need to fix?

Comment: Why are you referencing the build output of a different project as a `<Reference>` instead of a project reference in the first place?

Comment: Because I did not design our (very large) teams' build system, using References is more of a requirement I must satisfy than a decision that I am able to make. I believe the reason is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047733/project-reference-vs-dll-reference-which-is-better#comment14233307_3048041

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2733113/5749914, Visual Studio will search a number of locations for the DLL, and the fact that a clean build is working with a incorrect hint path indicates the hint path is not needed.

In this case, the $(outDir) was being searched: in my project, the outputPath tag was

```
<OutputPath>..\..\..\..\..\Build\UnitTests\</OutputPath>.
```

which was the same directory my project was being built to.

So, if the referenced DLL is in the **same build directory** that the project is being built to, there is no need for a hintpath.

Comment: For example I have next `<Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>` Should version of reference be the same as in hint path or it doesn't matter?