# How to use RCL as assembly in Maui project?

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, wwwroot, razor-class-library

It seems that I don't understand how to properly connect rcl to the Maui project. And I can't find approach that will help me.

In the example below I tried to reuse component from the RCL. Firstly css doesn't work at all. I tried a lot of stuff, but nothing give the expected result. These are some attempts add it to [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnveB.png).

```
<link href="_content/RCL7/RCL7.bundle.scp.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_content/RCL7/RCL7.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/RCL7.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_content/RCL7/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have read a lot about css isolation, but it doesn't work for me, or I just don't understand how to use it properly.
Secondly I tried to use static files from the wwwroot folder. You can see [shared component from RCL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB3qR.png)

```
<div class="my-component">
    This component is defined in the <strong>RCL7</strong> library.
    <img class="spinner" src="background.png" width="64" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

and it has an image with the svg icon. In the Maui project I tried to add this component to the [Index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTt0y.png).

```
    @page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<RCL7.Component1 />

Welcome to your new app.

<img class="spinner" src="_content/RCL7/img/clock.svg" width="64" alt="Loading..." />
```

And tried to add svg icon directly from the wwwroot folder. But both of them give me the same [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kZ3o.png) that it can't find the icon...
Here is the link to GitHub for this testing project - https://github.com/BeaverMyName/MauiTesting7. I will be very grateful if you can help me to understand what is wrong with my approach. Thank you.

Comment: You're test project on Github is probably Private.

Comment: You should also show code directly in the question rather that as images. - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thank you. I changed it according to your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Github project you need to do two things:

1. You need to reference the *RCL7* project in *TheMauiTesting7* for any `_content/???` references to work.

Here's the entry in the project file:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\RCL7\RCL7\RCL7.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

In your library component you need to reference the image correctly i.e. the fully qualified path from any site using the library:

```cs
<div class="my-component">
    This component is defined in the <strong>RCL7</strong> library.
    <img class="spinner" src="/_content/RCL7/img/clock.svg" width="64" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

The net result is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. So I must add it as a project? I can't just use it as a dll file (assembly reference)?

Comment: I don't believe so for mapping resources.  Either a directly linked project, or a Nuget package.

Comment: @Beaver You can refer to this case: [Project reference vs. DLL Reference - Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047733/project-reference-vs-dll-reference-which-is-better). It talks about project and dll.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT Yes, I understand it. The problem is that RCL located in a separate repo. Therefore I can't refer to it as a project. That is why I asked about the assembly reference.